# How can I add a character to folder names using batch

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I've got a series of folders on a Windows server which are a numerical sequence 92001, 92002, etc. and I need to add a '0'at the start of all these folders.

Rather than do this tedious task manually for the next two weeks, I was hoping to create a batch file to get it done much faster. How can I do this?

Comment: How's that batch creation going? Getting held up at a particular spot? There's no question in your question.

Comment: The answer below got everything the way I wanted it. Thank you for checking in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /D %%f in (*) do rename "%%f" "0%%f"
```

Comment: @Moses - The code is only renaming folders because of the FOR /D option, so there is no need to worry about the batch file renaming itself.

Comment: @dbenham Sorry I didn't notice the `/D` switch, correct you are!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had to take out the extra % signs to run it from a command line, but otherwise it worked great!

Comment: Yup, you need the double %% only when running from a .bat file